# 誤ったマイナス票の取り消し方は？

Tags: サポート

・誤ってマイナス票を入れてしまいました
・時間が経っていたためか、再度クリックしても戻りません
・プラス票を押しても、反応しません
・取り消すための、何か良い方法はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 4):

質問や回答に対する投票は、**投票から5分間に限り**、同じボタンを再度クリックすることで取り消し、またはもう片方のボタンを押すことで変更できます。

それを過ぎると、投稿が編集されない限り投票を取り消すことはできません。

<sub>[無期限に取り消せるようにしてほしい、という要望も出てはいる](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19021/286934)ものの、却下されていますね。。</sub>

Comment: 却下理由は、「leads to a lot of exploits」らしいですね。確かに悪用はできそうな気はしますが、具体的にどんな「exploits」が横行したのかが気になるところですね。

Comment: @YukiInoue 「このサイトを辞めたい！」前に、自分の数千投票を取り消したら、信用度が大幅変わってきます（歴史で一回大幅信用度を再計算したら、ユーザーがかなり怒られました。今でもSock Puppetを利用しているユーザーの投票を無効にすると、信用度をなくした第三者がよくクレームする）。そして、これを実行するとSock Puppetの投票等が見えづらくなる可能性もあります。なぜと説明したくないですが、当社側からこのような理由はあります。

Comment: @jmac 「歴史で一回大幅信用度を再計算したら、ユーザーがかなり怒られました。」 信用度を再計算したらユーザー*から*かなり怒られた*ことが過去にあった*、でしょうか？

Comment: @unarist 英語版の最初の頃に、信用度が自動的に計算してなくて、定期的にスクリプトで再計算しました。例えば、ユーザーが削除したら、そのスクリプトで信用度が下がりました。2011年に一回全ユーザーを再計算した結果「信用度が200点下がりました！なぜ？！？！？！」とかの起こっているユーザーが多かったです（[例](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862)）。その1年後、再計算を自動にしましたので、同じように怒りの声がありました：http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319